# NullPointerException when calling a method on another Groovy class

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception

I have the following two Groovy classes:

**Buzz.groovy**:

```
import widgets.Fizz

class Buzz {

    def WhistleFeather

    def init = { servletContext ->
        WhistleFeather.load()
        println "WhistleFeather loaded."
    }

    def destroy = { }
}
```

**WhistleFeather.groovy**:

```
package net.me.myapp

import widgets.Fizz

public class WhistleFeather {

    def navMenu

    def load() {        
        println "Loading!"
    }
}
```

When execution gets to the `WhistleFeather.load()` method call I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WhistleFeather#load` is an instance method, not a static method. Either call it with `new WhistleFeather().load(),` or turn it into a static method (`static load() { ... }`).

Comment: My apologies @Peter Niederwieser (+1) - please see my edits. The `def` has changed since I originally posted it. Thoughts?

Comment: Apparently the `WhistleFeather` variable is never initialized. Therefore its value is `null`, and calling a method on a `null` value causes a `NullPointerException`. PS: Variable names should start with a lower-case letter. In Groovy, you can even get some surprises if you don't follow this convention.